# Using Union All with IF ELSE Condition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to union a query result with another query result coming from IF ELSE condition. Below is my query:

```
set @x=0;
set @y=1;
select 33 as A from dual
union all
IF @x=@y then 
select 44 as A from dual 
else 
select 55 as A from dual
ELSE IF;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add it to where clause. Like below

```
set @x=0;
set @y=0;
select 33 as A from dual
union all 
select 44 as A from dual 
where 
@y = @x  
union all
select 55 as A from dual
where 
@y != @x
```

**Updated:** You can use stored procedure like below.

```
drop procedure proc_name;
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_name`(
    IN `x` int, IN `y` int
)

BEGIN 
if( x = y )then
    set @a = 'select 33 as A from dual
union all 
select 44 as A from dual ';
else 
    set @a = 'select 33 as A from dual
union all 
select 55 as A from dual ';
end if;     

    PREPARE stmt FROM @a;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
DELIMITER ;

call proc_name(1,0);
```

Comment: Thanks but It's a costly solution. It will execute both the statements. Actually, this is just an example query. In actual, my table is very large and your solution will traverse whole table on both statements. So It would be better if there is any IF ELSE solution.

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas Updated answer.

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas Have you looked at procedure ? That can be easily handled via procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without needing a stored-procedure. 
Using the function CASE.

**Query**

```
SET @x = 0;
SET @y = 1; 

SELECT 33 AS A FROM DUAL

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
 CASE 
   WHEN @x = @y 
   THEN 44
   ELSE 55 
 END AS a
FROM DUAL
```

**Result**

```
     A  
--------
      33
      55
```

**Query**

```
SET @x = 0;
SET @y = 0; 

SELECT 33 AS A FROM DUAL

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
 CASE 
   WHEN @x = @y 
   THEN 44
   ELSE 55 
 END AS a
FROM DUAL
```

**Result**

```
     A  
--------
      33
      44
```